# palindrome of string gets segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Just for fun I have written a function to check if string given is palindrome. When I run the prog it throws segmentation fault. Could anyone please throw light on it.

```
int palindrome( const char *input )         
{    
  char * reverse;    
  int len     = 0 ;     
  int i       = 0;     
  bool result = false;    
  len         = strlen(input);    

  if( len <= 1)   
    return  -1;     
  reverse  = (char *)malloc( sizeof ( char)* len);     
  printf( " the len of character is %d", len);        
  while( input[i++] != '/0')     
  {     
     reverse[ --len] = input[i];         
  }
  reverse[len] = '/0';

 printf(" the reverse string is %s", reverse);
 if( !strcmp( input, reverse) )
   return 1;
 else
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks
Sam

---

Changing the code as per suggestions to:

```
int palindrome( const char *input )         
{    
  char * reverse;    
  int len     = 0 ;     
  int i       = 0;     
  bool result = false;    
  len         = strlen(input)+1;    

  if( len <= 2)   
    return  -1;     
  reverse  = (char *)malloc(len);     
  printf( " the len of character is %d", len); 
  reverse[len] = '\0' ;      
  while( input[i++] != '\0')     
  {     
     reverse[ --len] = input[i];         
  }

 printf(" the reverse string is %s", reverse);
 if( !strcmp( input, reverse) )
   return 1;
 else
 return 0;
}
```

I still have a problem. The segmentation fault has disappeared but the reversed string is empty.

Comment: Voting to close as this is just a wall of code, but to get you on your way you're a day late and *a byte short*.

Comment: i apology but i didn't get what you mean

Comment: i wrote that function . had it been copied from somewhere I wouldn't get fault. I posted it here to understand where I am making mistake and to enhance my knowledge in pointers

Comment: Please don't change your questions in a way that invalidates the answers to date. It's okay to _augment_ the question with more information, which I've done in an edit. And please ensure you give us the _actual_ code. You have `reverse` and `reserve` in that sample which I assume was a typo (also fixed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

- the null terminator for strings is `'\0'`, not `'/0'`.
- `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1, you don't need to multiply by it.
- you should always allocate enough space for a string *and* its null terminator such as with `strlen(s) + 1`.
- you should not cast the return value from `malloc` in C, it hides certain errors that you would be better off knowing about.
- since you're gradually reducing `len` to populate the reverse string, it will end up as 0, not usable for placing the null terminator at the *end* of that string. This is probably the *immediate* cause of your core dump since calling `strcmp` on a non-null-terminated string is a bad idea.
- it's not really necessary to create a reversed string at all, you can just check the first and last characters, then the second and second-to-last and so on (until they meet in the middle, or cross over).

On that last point, what I mean is something like (pseudo-code):

```
def isPalindrome (str):
    left = 0
    right = strlen(str) - 1
    while left < right:
        if str[left] <> str[right]:
            return false
        left = left + 1
        right = right - 1
    return true
```

---

And, with the update, you have the right idea, setting the null terminator fist before reducing `len`.

But since, `len` is now the string length plus one, you're populating indexes 1 thru LEN rather than 0 thru LEN-1.

Change:

```
reverse[len] = '\0';
```

to:

```
reverse[--len] = '\0';
```

Or, better yet, change it so that `len` is still the length of the string (for `printf`):

```
len = strlen (input) + 1;
:
reverse = malloc (len);
```

to:

```
len = strlen (input);
:
reverse = malloc (len + 1);
```

Comment: I have modified the code with the first 3 points u made. and before while loop I have added reverse[len] = '\0'; ow i am not getting segmentation fault but string is null

Comment: @samprat Do the 5th point also. Think about what the value of `len` is when your loop is done.

Comment: @samprat: you need to work this thru a debugger (gdb, Eclipse, Visual Studio) yourself rather than SO. It'll help you catch where you've made the mistake (take a look at the value of `len` when you write the `\0` to reverse...)

Comment: I am creating reserve string because I am mainly trying to test my knowledge and reserving string will def help me in clearing few doubts  else i would have run for loop and check what u have mentioned

Comment: made the changes but string reverse s still null though there is no segmentation fault

Comment: @samprat: your new code has a slight off-by-one error, see my update.

Comment: @paxdiablo , Thanks mate , this is working now. Thanks to everyone for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

A string with `len` characters in it needs a buffer of `len+1` characters, because of the null character at the end.

Comment: i added +1 inline and still its segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I just have tested it and it works.

```
int palindrome( const char *input )         
{    
char * reverse;    
int len     = strlen(input);     
int i       = 0;     

if( len <= 1)   
    return  -1;

reverse  = (char *)malloc( sizeof(char) * len + 1);     
printf( " the len of character is %d", len);        
reverse[len--] = '\0';
while( input[i] != '\0')     
{     
    reverse[len--] = input[i++];         
}

printf(" the reverse string is %s", reverse);
if( !strcmp( input, reverse) )
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: If hope was functional code, you'd probably be right :-) This still has the problems (1) not allocating enough memory; (2) casting malloc; (3) wrong string terminators (4) superfluous sizeof(char). - With your edit, you've fixed the fatal #3 but #1 still means undefined behaviour.